# Gradle Exec Task to stop tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, cmd, gradlew

I am looking at this documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html which gives an example how to turn off/on tomcat.

However its not explained very well what exactly parameters commandLine expects.

So, the code below is failing. Could you please share any thoughts ?

```html
task stopTomcat(type:Exec) {
    println "$System.env.TOMCAT"

    workingDir "${System.env.TOMCAT}" + '/bin/'

    //on windows:
    commandLine './catalina.sh stop'

    //on linux
    //commandLine './stop.sh'

    //store the output instead of printing to the console:
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

I have configured my task as above, but it does fail when i run the task.

> Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not
>   start './catalina stop'

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows or Unix?

Generally, you need to identify the appropriate command that works for you at a command-line terminal on your platform. Then use the appropriate "platform style" in your Gradle task.

For example, I have Tomcat 7.x. To shutdown on Unix, using a terminal in `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin`, I would use `./shutdown.sh`. In this case, the task would use only:

```
  commandLine './shutdown.sh'
```

On Windows, I would use `shutdown.bat`. In this case, the task would use:

```
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'shutdown.bat'
```

Note that it is using `cmd` to call the BAT file. Because of the way Windows works, the commandLine would have that form for any BAT file.